# Every alternate page reload I am getting 412 Precondition Failed , its happening only in the chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tomcat

Every alternate page reload I am getting 412 Precondition Failed , its happening only in the chrome browser,But in IE and Firefox it working properly how many time Reloaded its working. 
Tried all the possible methods but still I am not able to solve it .

```
<body onload="noBack();" onunload="">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var popupWindows = new Array();
        var popupNames = new Array();
        window.onload = maxWindow;

        window.onunload = function(){

        }

        window.onbeforeunload = function() {

        }
```

Onunload function will not work in chrome ,but still how page will load alternate time , how is that possible. 
Can any one please help me out ?

**Updated**

[image]

```
POST http://localhost:8080/index.html 412 (Precondition failed)
```

Comment: Is there an exception with stacktrace in your apache tomcat log files?

Comment: No,i don't have any exception in log file. Every alternate reload  HTTP/1.1" 412 1005 is logged

Comment: But i am getting error in the console . Please check the error in the updated part .